# How to solve error EOF connecting to InfluxDB?

Tags: docker, eof

I'm using InfluxDB 1.8 and Grafana through docker for months without any problem until today. Suddenly I can't access InfluxDB. The error I get is:

```
Failed to connect to http://localhost:8086: Get http://localhost:8086/ping: EOF
Please check your connection settings and ensure 'influxd' is running.
```

Docker is running, it's checked. Some tests I did were to restart docker, change the port, run InfluxDB without docker, and finally try it without the databases (all empty).

It only works when I delete the databases, but then I lose all the content. I thought that maybe some file is corrupt but I don't know which one. Any idea how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Well, I finally deleted the corrupted file but the EOF error persists. However, now if I run the verify tool there are no broken blocks. Maybe it is because it cannot be deleted directly and there are references to its content somewhere?

Comment: I'm writing this down in case it helps anyone else. I had InfluxDB running for months on a HDD, from the time it first failed, it failed even with an empty DB, so I couldn't figure out where the problem was. It was fixed when I ran InfluxDB on an SSD, it hasn't happened since.

Answer (score 7):

If you suspect that the files might be corrupted, you could make use of following tools to verify the integrity of TSM files:

```
influx_inspect verify -dir <storage_root>
```

See more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/influx_inspect/#verify).

Comment: Yep, all the files are healthy except one that indicates:
\InfluxDB\data\_internal\monitor\976\000000030-000000001.tsm: could not get checksum for key [] block 988 due to error: "tsm file closed"
Now it's time to find out what it is and how to fix it